# Directory Structure of Struts2 + Hibernate + Maven in Eclipse

Tags: hibernate, maven-2

Can anyone please help me with a view of the complete directory structure of a Struts2 project with Hibernate and Maven..? I have to know where the configuration files, other resources(css,images,jsp, etc.) have to be placed. I know this too outdated but I'm unable to find a appropriate structure. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Maven Directory Structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

This directory structure is irrespective of web framework or orm frameworks you elect to use in your application.

You would place struts.xml and hibernate.properties into the `src\main\resources` directory.

Comment: Whether I should place my stylesheets and images inside the `src\main\resources` or Can I create a separate folder to place all my resources..? @Naros

Comment: @JayaramJai You would likely want to place them inside the `src\main\webapp` folder in subfolders based on item types such as `css`, `js`, and `images`.

Comment: So I can create a folder with some name inside the webapps folder and I have to create subfolders inside it based on whether it is css or images etc..? Thanks I got it @Naros

Answer (score 0):

When we doing in Maven project.. Maven has a different structure as follows

Here In Srs have Main,test are main Resource folders.

coming to Main folder. it has java and webapps sub folders

In "java" packages are place and these are having .java ,.js, .jquery files

In "webapps" packages are place and these are having .jsp, .html, etc,. files. It is realated to web applications.

it show like

```
src/main/java
src/main/webapps
```

coming to Test folder. it has java and webapps or some other depends upon wht type of application you have to test. and what type of testing tools your using.

it shows like:

```
src/test/java
src/test/webapps
```

We create files to test the application using Junit testcases or other test cases.

Finally one more folder called "Resources". This is used to place Mapping files or config files here like .xml, .cfg.xml, .hbm.xml, etc.

```
src/main/resource
```

So, these are the generally standard structure of Maven.. but we can create own structure.  by NEW--> SOURCE FOLDER and give some name.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank U @rajawin2008...This gives me a overall view...But my Whether I should place my stylesheets and images inside the src\main\resources or Can I create a separate folder to place all my resources..?

Answer (score 0):

well when you want to web application it is like below..

trucks  contains src folder and pom.xml

src/main/webapp contains index.jsp and WEB-INF folder.

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF contains web.xml

src/main/resources  it contains images/properties files .

Just to clarify this is what I had to do:

Make sure that in your

```
servlet-context.xml you have as follows:

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Create a folder if does not already exist under webapps called resources

Place your css folder along with css files there

Reference my css file as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/960.css"/>
```

Comment: Thank U @rajawin2008...It really helps a lot